# Need help merging unallocated partition to primary partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I triple-booted and realized I did not want Mac OS X anymore. So I simply deleted it's partition. But now I am trying to move half of the unallocated to windows and half of it to Ubuntu. I am having a great deal of issues doing this. Any help appreciated.Thanks!

Here is a picture of all my partitions.

[image]

Comment: Tell us at least anything about the great deal of issues so that anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD to be able to move Ubuntu partitions. You see that now they are locked with "key" sign.

After that you will be able to move all partitions. But do not mount them in Nautilus, otherwise they will be locked again. But you can unmount partitions using right-click in Gparted.

But you may have trouble with "Microsoft reserved partition". It can be unmovable. In this case the easiest way is to create 2 new partitions using unallocated space.

You can format one of new partitions to ext4 and mount it in Ubuntu and format the other one to NTFS and use it in Windows.

Another way is to backup /dev/sda5 with Clonezilla and restore it in the unallocated space. It is just enough for that.

There are some other ways using LVM, but it is not that easy.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will be trying this shortly. I will let you know if it works.